# End execution of Thread without using its stop() method

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a Swing form with a button, which is when clicked starts `SocketServer` for listening to incoming requests in a separate thread. Following is structure of classes I have.

- `MainForm` : This is my main class which launches Swing Form. It has two buttons, "start server" and "stop buttons".
- `MySocketServer` : This class is where `SocketServer` object exists, it has methods `startServer()` and `stopServer()`.

**Following is Start button's Click Event Body.**

```
t = new Thread(new Runnable() //Object t is created globally in this main class.
{
    public void run()
    {
        myss = new MySocketServer(); //Object myss has similar accessibility as t.
        myss.startServer();
    }
});
t.start();
```

**And Following is Stop Button's Click Event Body**

```
myss.stopServer();
if(t.isAlive());
    System.out.println("Thread is still alive!!");
```

Though I can toggle SockeServer "start" and "stop" as my times I want, but I realize that everytime I start the server, new thread gets created and it remains active even though server is stopped using `MySocketServer`'s method.

I can use `stop()` of `Thread` and stop the thread execution but since it is depreciated and I have studied that threads get ended once their `run()` method has executed completely, but I have `startServer()` method separated so that it can handle connected clients separately.

Please note that `startServer()` has While-Listen loop, so essentially `run()` method of thread is in infinite state of execution, until I explicitly call `stopServer()` and halt the loop.

what can be done here?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you are right to not try to use `Thread.stop()`.  It is potentially dangerous.

So what should you do?

One possibility might to be to write your server thread like this:

```
    ....
    ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(...);
    try {
       while (keepGoing) {
           Socket s = ss.accept(...);
           try {
               // do stuff
           } finally {
               // close socket
           }
       }
    } finally {
       // close the server socket
    }
```

and have `stopServer` clear the `keepGoing` flag.  But the problem is that the stop typically will come while the thread is blocked in the `accept` call, and there's nothing to unblock it.

Another possibility might be to call `Thread.interrupt()` on the thread.  That causes some things to unblock, and throw an exception, but I don't think it will unblock the `accept()` call though.  (However, this is still better than setting a flag if the "do stuff" part needs interrupting.)

The real solution (I think) is to close the `ServerSocket`.  This will cause the `ss.accept()` call to unblock and throw an exception, which you need to handle in the server thread.

Comment: as you suggested to close the `ServerSocket`, I'm already doing both in my `stopServer()` method of main class, closing the ServerSocket, and setting the boolean flag to false which would eventually end the loop. So I believe that `run()` method is actually ending its execution, but still I get `isAlive()` true for the thread.

Comment: set the while condition in the above code to:   ! ss.isClosed()   Then, if you simply call ss.close() from whatever method is to shut the server down, the accept method will unblock and throw a SocketException, which you should be able to safely catch and ignore by checking the ss.isClosed() flag in your catch block.

Answer (score 0):

In your MySocketServer class in the while loop you need a flag which will test if it should keep running or not.

In your newly added shutdown method set the flag which the loop in the thread will test. Once the loop breaks and run() returns the thread will end.

Comment: I have boolean flag which is used in `serverStart()` method, which is checked upon each iteration of loop, and I set this flag to false in `startServer()`, while debugging now I came to know that while loop terminates upon calling `stopServer()`, and even the `run()` method of thread completes its execution elegantly, but why am I getting `isAlive()` true even if run is completed?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use stop(). Take a look at this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/threadPrimitiveDeprecation.html
The solution with infinite loop and start/stop flags is straightforward but leads to ineffective using of CPU time. The better way is to use wait/notify approach. The way you operate with MySocketServer gives me feeling that you have other infinite loop inside the startServer(). That's why you have to stop it. It would be better to wrap this loop into it's own thread internally and make start/stop methods operate with this thread state in wait/notify manner.
Forgot to mention, as your GUI runs in its own thread you can't escape start/stop flag inside the MySocketServer because using wait() in GUI thread will make it hanged.